# Using TPrototypeBindSource to automatically update properties in an object

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, livebindings

I'm trying to use livebindings to update properties of my (non-component) objects.  I have a TPrototypeBindSource that I am using to bind components to my objects fields, and using a TObjectBindSourceAdapter at run time.  I can get it to work if call `MyPrototypeBindSource.Refresh` in the onchange event of the edit components, but is there a way to get this to happen automatically, without setting up the onchange event for every component on my form?

Comment: You mean other than creating a single OnChange event and attaching it to all edit controls?

Comment: That hadn't occurred to me, but I also thought live bindings were able to push changes without calling a manual refresh?  Or am i mistaken about how they work?

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to do so, although I must admit my experience with LiveBindings is limited to several smaller apps. (We still have the majority of our apps in an earlier version of Delphi that doesn't support them.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is `TPrototypeBindSource.AutoPost` which I [suspect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Bind.ObjectScope.TPrototypeBindSource.AutoPost) to handle the automatic post of the control data to the data object it does not ... well looking at the source, this property just influence the internal data generator.

Seems to be, we have to set this property by hand when creating the adapter (and because we are just at this point we will set the `AutoEdit` as well):

```
procedure TForm1.PrototypeBindSource1CreateAdapter( Sender: TObject; var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter );
begin
  FPerson := TPerson.Create;
  ABindSourceAdapter := TObjectBindSourceAdapter<TPerson>.Create( Self, FPerson );
  ABindSourceAdapter.AutoEdit := True;
  ABindSourceAdapter.AutoPost := True;
end;
```

This will do the job, every time you **leave** an `TEdit` but a `TCheckBox`
 will post the data immediately.

To change this just use a `published` method

```
procedure TForm1.ControlChanged( Sender: TObject );
begin
  if Sender is TComponent
  then
    TLinkObservers.ControlChanged( Sender as TComponent );
end;
```

and assign this to each needed control (e.g. `TEdit.OnChange`) to get the data immediately to the data object.

Here the whole in one go

```
type
  TPerson = class
  private
    FFirstname: string;
    FLastname: string;
    FActive: Boolean;
  public
    function ToString: string; override;

    property Active: Boolean read FActive write FActive;
    property Firstname: string read FFirstname write FFirstname;
    property Lastname: string read FLastname write FLastname;
  end;

  TForm1 = class( TForm )
    PersonSource: TPrototypeBindSource; { OnCreateAdapter -> PersonSourceCreateAdapter }
    Edit1: TEdit; { OnChange -> ControlChanged }
    Edit2: TEdit; { OnChange -> ControlChanged }
    BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
    LinkControlToField1: TLinkControlToField;
    LinkControlToField2: TLinkControlToField;
    Label1: TLabel;
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents; { OnIdle -> ApplicationEvents1Idle }
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    LinkControlToField3: TLinkControlToField;
    procedure PersonSourceCreateAdapter( Sender: TObject; var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter );
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Idle( Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean );
  private
    FPerson: TPerson;
  published
    procedure ControlChanged( Sender: TObject );
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Idle( Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean );
begin
  // just for checking then object data
  Label1.Caption := FPerson.ToString;
end;

procedure TForm1.ControlChanged( Sender: TObject );
begin
  if Sender is TComponent
  then
    TLinkObservers.ControlChanged( Sender as TComponent );
end;

procedure TForm1.PersonSourceCreateAdapter( Sender: TObject; var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter );
begin
  FPerson := TPerson.Create;
  ABindSourceAdapter := TObjectBindSourceAdapter<TPerson>.Create( Self, FPerson );
  ABindSourceAdapter.AutoEdit := True;
  ABindSourceAdapter.AutoPost := True;
end;

{ TPerson }

function TPerson.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := FLastname + ', ' + FFirstname + ' ' + BoolToStr( FActive );
end;
```

LiveBindings:

```
Active    : ftBoolean -> CheckBox1/CheckedState(Self)
Firstname : ftString  -> Edit1/Text
Lastname  : ftString  -> Edit2/Text
```

---

If you do not like to assign the `ControlChanged` method to all controls you can force the `TPrototypeBindSource` to post the data by calling `TPrototypeBindSource.Post`. But you have to check first if it is in edit mode:

```
if PersonSource.Editing
then
  PersonSource.Post;
```

Call this whenever you need to have the data posted ... if at any time just call it within `TApplicationEvents.OnIdle`.

Comment: I had assumed that the AutoPost setting would carry over from the Prorotype.  For most cases, getting it on exit will be good enough for most uses. Thanks.

Comment: You are not alone with that and I had to look at the source why it is not :o)

Comment: If you accept that your TEdit updates your binded TObject *only* on the TEdit's OnExit event, then TLinkObservers.ControlChanged is not required